# Is this is a legal transaction? Not working for some reason

Tags: android, android-studio, addition, onactivityresult

So it appears that myList.add(s) is not working. I was just wondering if anyone would be able to tell me why? Pretty new to this - can I not call .add in my onActivityResult? Thanks!

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // get Object from file
    Object obj = getObjectFromFile(this, myFileName);
    // if obj returns something, check it's type
    if (obj != null && obj instanceof ArrayList) {
        // use the existing List id it exists
        myList = (ArrayList<toDo>) obj; //notice the arraylist is of type student
    } else {
        // create new List if one doesn't exist
        //myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        myList = new ArrayList<toDo>();
    }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if ((requestCode == 101) && (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)) {
        Bundle myResults = data.getExtras();
        String activity1 = myResults.getString("activity");
        String description1 = myResults.getString("description");
        String date1 = myResults.getString("date");
        String assignment1 = myResults.getString("assignment");
        txtMsg.setText(description1);
        s = new toDo(activity1, description1, date1, assignment1);
        myList.add(s);
        mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Are you getting an exception?

Comment: No, I have code such that it should update my list view after I call add and then call notifyDataSetChanged and it is not updating that list view

Comment: Show where you initialize mArrayAdapter